# Is it possible to make an IL project in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, mono, monodevelop, cil

In [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22) for the `dotnet new` command, the only languages listed for the various options are C#, F#, and VB. In MonoDevelop version 7.8.2, I also only see C#, F#, and VB under the options for creating a new .NET Core project.

However, in MonoDevelop under the Other -> .NET section, which would create a project using Mono, I can choose between C#, F#, VB, and IL. Selecting IL creates a `.ilproj` file for the project. It seems that I can only use IL with Mono, not .NET Core, unless I'm missing something.

While I do want an actual answer to this, to  explain what I'm trying to do and avoid the XY problem, I was thinking about just as an experiment / for fun making my own programming language, and I would like to output IL that can be used by .NET Core or Mono, but I'd need some way for it to build the generated IL. I think it would be better to use .NET Core if possible, hence the question.

Comment: Yes, there is support via the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL.targets (i think that is the name of the target)... Note This, like `xbuild` & `msbuild`, it using the `Ilasm.exe` (IL Assembler) to directly produce a PE assembly (i.e. there is no "magic" inside of Mono or .Net Core required). Search the dotnet repo for PRs/Issues involving "support for an ilproj sdk"...

Comment: Ilasm.exe (IL Assembler) Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ilasm-exe-il-assembler

Answer (score 1):

[It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57762959/710069).

Here is the example: https://github.com/Konard/ILProj